# How to re-arrange the drives navigation pane to show local drives first

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-explorer

I am using Windows 10 x64. I recently upgraded from Windows 7 x64 when MS warnings about ending support for Windows 7 started appearing on my desktop.

I've managed to get most of my display settings back to the way they were in Windows 7 but can't seem to work out this problem.

In the tree-view of the navigation pane, windows lists the networked drives before the local ones.

[navigation pane listing networked drives before local ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rew0f.jpg)

This is not efficient since I often have 9-12 networked drives connected at one time or the other.

With my local drives being displayed at the bottom of the pane and I need to scroll down to click on them. I would really appreciate a way to have the local drives listed before the networked ones. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This is not a skill that Windows 10 Explorer has. If you need a particular layout, consider xPlorer2 (zabkat) as you can set up your layout and then save the settings for xPlorer2 to open that way all the time

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply John. I was hoping there'd be a registry hack or something for this. I will check out xPlorer2 in the mean time.